# same border for li as background

Tags: html, css

I have navigation menu and I would like to implement somehow a border which is the same as the background but when I try that the box shadow doesn't do the effect that I want.

This is what I want

[image]

can someone take a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fmB5R/1/

```
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(48, 48, 48);
box-shadow:0 0 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-shadow`'s [inset](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) property to get that effect:

```
  box-shadow:inset 2px 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/fmB5R/5/